Angular The file upload screen nothing happens
The file upload screen appears, but when I click upload, nothing happens.
A pop-up window should appear saying "Are you sure?"
As I show in this video, nothing happens.
Angular Side :
file-upload-component.ts :
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgxFileDropEntry, FileSystemFileEntry, FileSystemDirectoryEntry, NgxFileDropModule } from 'ngx-file-drop';
import { HttpClientService } from '../http-client.service';
import { AlertifyService, MessagePosition, MessageType } from '../alertify.service';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { FileUplaodDialogState, FileUploadDialogComponent } from '../../../dialogs/file-upload-dialog/file-upload-dialog.component';
import { DialogService } from '../dialog.service';
import { MatButton } from '@angular/material/button';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-file-upload',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgxFileDropModule,
    MatButton
  ],
  templateUrl: './file-upload.component.html',
  styleUrl: './file-upload.component.scss'
})
export class FileUploadComponent {

  constructor(
    private httpClient : HttpClientService,
    private alertift : AlertifyService,
    private dialog : MatDialog,
    private dialogService : DialogService
  ) 
  { }

  @Input() options : Partial<FileUploadOptions>;

  public files: NgxFileDropEntry[];

  public dropped(files: NgxFileDropEntry[]) {

    this.files = files;
    const formData = new FormData()
    for (const droppedFile of files) {
      (droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry).file((file: File) => {
        formData.append(droppedFile.relativePath, file, droppedFile.relativePath)
      })
    }

    this.dialogService.openDialog({
      componentType : FileUploadDialogComponent,
      data : FileUplaodDialogState.Yes,
      afterClosed  : () => {
        this.httpClient.post({
          controller : this.options.controller,
          action : this.options.action,
          queryString : this.options.queryString,
          headers : new HttpHeaders({ "responseType" : "blob" })
        },formData).subscribe(res => {
          this.alertift.message("Dosya veya dosyalar başarıyla yüklendi", {
            messagePosition : MessagePosition.TopRight,
            messageType  : MessageType.Success
          })
        },(errorResponse : HttpErrorResponse) => {  
          this.alertift.message("Dosya veya dosyalar yüklenirken hata oluştu", {
            messagePosition : MessagePosition.TopRight,
            messageType  : MessageType.Error
          })
        })
      }
    })
  }
}
  


export class FileUploadOptions {
   controller? : string;
   action? : string;
   queryString? : string;
   acceptedFiles? : string;
}



select-article-image-dialog.component.ts :
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseDialog } from '../base-dialog';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { FileUplaodDialogState } from '../file-upload-dialog/file-upload-dialog.component';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatButton } from '@angular/material/button';
import { FileUploadComponent, FileUploadOptions } from '../../services/common/file-upload/file-upload.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-select-article-image-dialog',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatDialogModule,
    MatButton,
    FileUploadComponent
  ],
  templateUrl: './select-article-image-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrl: './select-article-image-dialog.component.scss'
})
export class SelectArticleImageDialogComponent extends BaseDialog<SelectArticleImageDialogComponent> {

  constructor (dialogRef  : MatDialogRef<SelectArticleImageDialogComponent>, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data : SelectArticleImageState | string) {
    super(dialogRef)
  } 
    

  @Output() options : Partial<FileUploadOptions> = {
    acceptedFiles : ".png,.jpg,.jpeg",
    action : "upload",
    controller : "articles",
    queryString :`id=${this.data}`
  }



}

export enum SelectArticleImageState{
  Close
}

html page :
<h2 mat-dialog-title></h2>
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">
  
  <app-file-upload [options]="options"></app-file-upload>

</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>



Server side :
 [HttpPost("[action]")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(string id)
 {
     List<(string fileName, string pathOrContainerName)> result = await _storageService.UploadAsync("images", Request.Form.Files, _webHostEnvironment);

     await _articleImageFileWriteRepository.AddRangeAsync(result.Select(x => new ArticleImageFile()
     {
         FileName = x.fileName,
         Path = x.pathOrContainerName,
         Storage = "Local",
     }).ToList());

     await _articleImageFileWriteRepository.SaveAsync();
     return Ok();
 }


I tried many things but I couldn't figure it out
